# Using Bulk Copy Program / Linked Server to transfer Excel-VBA file into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, excel, cmd, ssms, vba

I have an excel-vba file with about 15000 rows and 4 columns. I need to insert 2 of the columns into Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I have been looking at YouTube tutorials for how to do this but am very new so I got lost.

I have tried to convert my file into a `.text` file so I could insert it into the SQL server. I also tried to do linked server method but it did not seem to work -- if you have advice on a way to make that work instead, that is welcome as well!

**Code in SSMS:**

```
CREATE TABLE ExportTool(TOOLING_SHEET CARCHAR, TOOLS VARCHAR)

INSERT INTO ExportTool VALUES "insert some range here...

SELECT * from ExportTool
```

** **EDITED CODE IN SSMS:** **

```
CREATE TABLE ImportTool(TOOLING_SHEET CARCHAR, TOOLS VARCHAR)

BULK INSERT dbo.ImportTool
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'J:\test-TDS\tools.text');
WITH
    (
    /* insert some range here */
    )

Select * from ImportTool
```

**Using cmd:**

```
DEV.dbo.ExportTool OUT J:\test-TDS\TOOLS.txt -T -c
```

**ENTER:** gave the output 0 rows copied

```
DEV.dbo.ExportTool OUT J:\test-TDS\TOOLS.text -T -c
```

**ENTER:** gave the output :

```
Error = unable to open BCP host data-file
```

Am I typing something into the cmd incorrectly that it is not copying the files? And how do I alter my code in SSMS to get the information from that file. I cannot find where I am going wrong.

Comment: I thought you were trying to Import to SQL Server?  Those BCP commands look like *Export* commands to me.

Comment: @RBarryYoung wow yes of course. Thank you! Do you know what I would put in the SSMS code to get the information to go from the file J:\test-TDS\TOOLS.text into the SQL server?

Comment: Either change OUT to IN in the BCP command, or use a `BULK INSERT` command in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, perfect, I have been trying to use BULK INSERT for this but everything I have looked up seems to need to specify a range to choose from. Can I not just import the entire file or select all of the occupied cells or something of that nature? I have edited the question to include my current BUL INSERT code @RBarryYoung